# Link on post title only if post have content

Tags: php, functions, get-posts

Hello i create an archive.php custom for category-id (category-id.php) and use this code

```
    <?php
/**
* A Simple Category Template
*/
 
get_header(); ?> 
 
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" role="main">
 
<?php 
// Check if there are any posts to display
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 
<header class="archive-header">

</header>




 <?php
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <div><p>
     <?php if( get_field('telefono') ): ?>Telefono: <?php the_field('telefono'); ?>      
     <?php endif; ?>
     
     <?php if( get_field('email') ): ?> Email <?php the_field('email'); ?>    
     <br />
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if( get_field('indirizzo') ): ?> Indirizzo: <?php the_field('indirizzo'); ?> 
     <br /> 
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if( get_field('link_mappa') ): ?>
     <a href="<?php the_field('link_mappa'); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> <img src="https://www.mondosup.it/wp-content/uploads/link_mappa_scuole_sup.png" width="250" /></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
</p>
</div>
 
<?php endwhile; 
 
else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 
 
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</section>
 
 
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I display under title ACF field. Now i'd like to put link on single post only if the post have content.

I try with some code but i cant'do that..is possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121359/if-the-post-has-content) question

Probably the easiest way would be:

```
<?php
// The Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ('' !== get_post()->post_content): ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
               title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div><p>
            <?php if (get_field('telefono')): ?>Telefono: <?php the_field('telefono'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (get_field('email')): ?> Email <?php the_field('email'); ?>
                <br/>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (get_field('indirizzo')): ?> Indirizzo: <?php the_field('indirizzo'); ?>
                <br/>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (get_field('link_mappa')): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('link_mappa'); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> <img
                            src="https://www.mondosup.it/wp-content/uploads/link_mappa_scuole_sup.png" width="250"/></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;

else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>


<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </section>


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```